# How to exclude files and folders from codecov scan?

Tags: java, jenkins, code-coverage, codecov

How can I exclude some files and folders from codecov scan? I saw here [docs](https://docs.codecov.io/docs/ignoring-paths), that I should use an ignorePaths element in codecov.yml. I did so, but codecov still scans those files?

Answer (score 2):

I saw in our jenkins log that codecov is taking the code from git/docker file and the path that was in use - was not the path as I saw it in our git repo.
the path that I used (for instance) -

```
ignore:
  - "app/src/main/java/com/abc/Application.java"
```

While the path in practice was :

```
ignore:
  - "bundle/app/src/main/java/com/abc/Application.java"
```

Comment: Where exactly do you put this?

Comment: @TimRutter `codecov.yml` in the root of your project